# Formatting JSON on console.log

Tags: node.js, json

Im trying to format this console.log removing the Curly Braces and the word token in it, just leaving the numbers out.

```
require('dotenv').config()
const twoFactor = require('node-2fa')
const newToken = twoFactor.generateToken(process.env.EAKEY)       

console.log(JSON.stringify(newToken))
```

This code outputs in console: {"token":"075701"}

I want it to output: 075701
Removing everything else

Thanks

Comment: Im getting undefined doin that

Comment: You mean `console.log(newToken.token)`?

Comment: Thanks it worked sorry for being noob

Comment: @jarmod, yes! thanks for correcting me! typed it fast.

Comment: If you don't want a JSON in the output then don't output a JSON. It is as simple as that. As a start you should output `newToken` then read about [objects in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to learn how to dump only the value you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log the token value as follows:

```
console.log(newToken.token)
```

For any property `y` of object `x`, you access the property via `x.y`.